# noUiSlider - double range slider with two inputs + vue.js

Tags: javascript, input, vue.js, nouislider

I want  a double range slider with two inputs in order to control the range.

Just like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w0UI.png

I also need to get it alongside with vue.js.

At the moment I have the following html:

```
   <div id="main">
        <br>
        <div id="slider"></div>
        <br>
        <input id="slider-input" v-model="third" v-on:change="updateSlider" />
    </div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
  var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        minRange: 40,
        slider: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            start: 40,
            step: 1
        },
        Slider: document.getElementById('slider')
    },
    methods: {
        updateSlider: function updateSlider() {
            this.Slider.noUiSlider.set(this.minRange);
        }
    },
    ready: function ready() {
        noUiSlider.create(this.Slider, {
            start: this.slider.start,
            step: this.slider.step,
            range: {
                'min': this.slider.min,
                'max': this.slider.max
            }
        });
    }
});

vue.$data.Slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
    vue.$data.minRange = values[handle];
});
```

With this I can have a range slider with one handler. I can drag the handler, update the values in the input and, also, write some new values and update the handler position (UI).

Now, I want to add another handler and do all the features I'm able to do with the one I have, right now.

How can I do this? (duplicate the input, add a data.maxRange, and...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the tweaks you'd need on the slider end:

Use two handles:

```
start: [this.slider.startMin, this.slider.startMax]
```

The update event must handle both:

```
vue.$data[handle ? 'maxRange' : 'minRange'] = values[handle];
```

In your `updateSlider` function:

```
this.Slider.noUiSlider.set([this.minRange, this.maxRange]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was almost there but your help was key.

Comment: Now I'm facing another problem: this script was using an outdated vue version. 
With the updated version, ready method is not fired. I've already changed to mounted but still doesn't work. Can't draw the slider bar.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly simple answer I came up with after needing the same thing.  I looked at the same slider and decided to come up with my own based on a js slider I found.  Below is the fiddle.

[js fiddle dual range slider in vuejs](https://jsfiddle.net/rsteen76/yrnjmLg7/13/)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    minPrice: "500",
    maxPrice: "50000"
  },
  methods: {
    slider: function() {
      if (this.minPrice > this.maxPrice) {
        var tmp = this.maxPrice;
        this.maxPrice = this.minPrice;
        this.minPrice = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 6em;
}

.range-slider svg,
.range-slider input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=number]:invalid,
input[type=number]:out-of-range {
  border: 2px solid #ff6347;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #2497e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  border: 1px solid #2497e3;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #a1d0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="range-slider">
    <span @change="slider">from <input v-model.number="minPrice" type="number"  min="0" max="120000"/> to <input  v-model.number="maxPrice" type="number"  min="0" max="120000"/></span>
    <input @change="slider" v-model.number="minPrice" min="0" max="120000" step="500" type="range" />
    <input @change="slider" v-model.number="maxPrice" min="0" max="120000" step="500" type="range" />
    <svg width="100%" height="24">
                          <line x1="4" y1="0" x2="300" y2="0" stroke="#444" stroke-width="12" stroke-dasharray="1 28"></line>
                        </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no it didn't, checked in FF 72+. I see input field with text "500"  and big slider that did not response on clicking

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its possible to tweak that component and make it a range slider.

There is a JQuery UI component which manages to do ranges:
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

And, it is possible to wrap JQuery UI components, and make them work in a Vue environment: 
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

If you can make the two to work together it will meet your requirement. Also, you would have to bundle JQuery and JQuery UI as dependencies.

Comment: **noUiSlider** (https://refreshless.com/nouislider) is a tool to create these kind of slider without no dependencies.

The screenshot I've linked is from a working example on their site.

My problem is exactly with the tool. This is possible and I won't need any dependency.

Thanks for your answer.